# findByUsername() returns blank page

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I'm learning nestjs with mongodb (mongoose) and I'm trying to get a single user from the database.

#### users.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private readonly userModel: Model<UserDocument>,) {}

    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
        const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
        return createdUser.save();
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.userModel.find().exec();
    }

    async findByUsername(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
        return this.userModel.findOne({username})
    }
}
```

#### users.controller.ts

```
@UseGuards()
@Controller('/api/users')
export class UsersController {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {
    }

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() user: CreateUserDto) {
        await this.usersService.create(user);
    }

    @Get()
    async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.usersService.findAll();
    }

    @Get(':username')
    async findOne(username: string): Promise<User> {
        return this.usersService.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

#### users.schema.ts

```
export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {
    @Prop()
    firstname: string;

    @Prop()
    lastname: string;

    @Prop({required: true})
    username: string;

    @Prop({required: true})
    password: string;

    @Prop({default: false})
    isAdmin: boolean;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Problem is that I receive a blank page when navigating to http://localhost:3000/api/users/username
and Postman isn't returning anything either.

[image: postman get]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that username returns something? Your screenshot doesn't show enough for me to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@Get(':username')` route handler defines that it should have a `username` parameter passed to it, but doesn't tell Nest *how* to pass it. You can do one of two things here:

1. use `@Param('username')` to pull the username directly from `req.params['username']`. Quick and easy
2. use `@Param() { username }` to deconstruct `req.params` to pull out just `username` (it should be the only value anyways). The benefit of this approach is being able to use the `ValidationPipe` with a DTO class to represent the `req.params` object. With the second approach, your `@Get(':username')` method would look like this:

```js
Get(':username')
async findOne(@Param() { username }: UsernameParams) {
  return this.usersService.findByEmail(username);
}
```